# How to add a different type of element to ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

In the code posted at the bottom, I'm trying to add to the existing legend a grey bar with label "Confidence interval". Can someone please help me add this to the legend? If this can be added to the existing legend, great; if it is cleaner to add a new legend just for this item, that's ok too. As a side comment, my ggplot code looks like quite long and messy for the simple plot that is rendered, maybe this is how ggplot code always ends up. I wonder if ggplot is worth it versus base R plot.

This image shows what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(survival)

lung1 <- lung %>% 
  mutate(time1 = ifelse(time >= 500, 500, time)) %>% 
  mutate(status1 = ifelse(status == 2 & time >= 500, 1, status))

weibCurve <- function(time, survregCoefs) {exp(-(time/exp(survregCoefs[1]))^exp(-survregCoefs[2]))}

fit1 <- survreg(Surv(time1, status1) ~ 1, data = lung1)

lung1.survfit <- survfit(Surv(time1, status1) ~ 1, data = lung1)
lung1.df <- data.frame(time = lung1.survfit$time, 
                       survival = lung1.survfit$surv, 
                       upper_95 = lung1.survfit$upper, 
                       lower_95 = lung1.survfit$lower)

lung1.df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = survival)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95), alpha = 0.2, fill = "grey") +
  geom_line(aes(y = survival, color = "Historical data"), size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1500)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Fraction surviving", color = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  stat_function(fun = weibCurve, args = list(survregCoefs = fit1$icoef), 
                aes(color = "Weibull distribution fit"), size = 1, n = 1000) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "grey"), 
                     labels = c("Historical data", "Weibull distribution fit", "Confidence intervals")) +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95), legend.justification = c(1, 1),
        legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.box.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"), 
        legend.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), legend.title = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we map the fill of the ribbon to the `fill` aesthetic, we can show a legend entry like your picture. To control what color is assigned to that fill, we can use `scale_fill_manual`, and we can put the fill legend after the color legend with `guide_legend(order = ...)`.

```
...
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95, fill = "Confidence Interval"), 
            alpha = 0.2) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("Confidence Interval" = "grey50"), name = NULL) +
guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1), fill  = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
...
```

[image]